# Laravel 5.6 : Check the column values in imported csv file using maat/website

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

In our project, we would like to put import csv file(we're using maat/website). We would like to check if the corresponding values in the csv file are correct so that we can save it in our table.

**Controller**

```
public function importCSVVendorList(Request $request)
{
    $data       =   $request->all();
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv'
    ]);
    // dd($validator->fails());
    //if validator fails
    // if ($validator->fails()) {
    //     return false;
    // }
    $path           = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $row_values     = Excel::load($path)->get();
    if($row_values->count() > 0)
    {
        foreach($row_values->toArray() as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == 1)
            {
            dd($value);

            }
            // foreach($value as $row)
            // {
            //     dd($row['code']);
            //     $vendor_lists       = array(
            //                              // 'Code' => $row['']
            //                           );
            // }
        }
    }
    dd($path);
}
```

**Value of my dd**

[image]

Question: How do we check the values in the csv file?

Comment: Do you mean [row valdation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html)?

Comment: Maybe try parse the csv to an array

Comment: @Remul do you have any example that uses jquery builder?

Comment: Can you give an example? @JellyBean